# C# Sum up values in Lists of List

Tags: c#, linq, sum

Is it possible to sum up all values in lists of List using only linq ? 
I have code that works, but maybe there is a way out with the LINQ that doesn't require foreach loop

```
        double totalSum = 0;
        Guid key = ((KeyValuePair<Guid, string>)ComboBoxUsers.SelectedItem).Key;
        var listOfLists = process._statistics.Where(a => a.UserID == key).Select(p => p.KgIntoBucket);

        foreach(List <double> kg in listOfLists)
        {
            totalSum += kg.Sum();

        }
        lblKgToBucket.Text = totalSum.ToString();
```

Comment: `double totalSum = listOfLists.SelectMany(list => list).Sum();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0) and it will help to flatten the sequence into one sequence:

```
var totalSum= listOfLists.SelectMany(x => x).Sum();
```

Comment: I put it all in one line                     
           `double listOfLists = process._statistics.Where(a => a.UserID == key).Select(p => p.KgIntoBucket).SelectMany(list => list).Sum();`

Comment: I prefer your previous approach , as its more easy to read and understand the logic:)

Comment: as you say, sir !

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test it, but I think you can write:

```
double sum = listOfLists.Select(innerList=>innerList.Sum()).Sum();
```

The `Select` method would return an `IEnumerable` with all the sublists sums and than it would sum it.

(I wrote it from my phone so sorry if there are problems in the code)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        List<List<double>> lstDouble = new List<List<double>>();


        List<double> items1 = new List<double>() { 1.231, 4.561, 10.891 };
        List<double> items2 = new List<double>() { 1.232, 4.562, 20.892 };
        List<double> items3 = new List<double>() { 1.233, 4.563, 7.893 };
        List<double> items4 = new List<double>() { 1.234, 30.564, 7.894 };
        List<double> items5 = new List<double>() { 40.235, 4.565, 7.895 };

        lstDouble.Add(items1);
        lstDouble.Add(items2);
        lstDouble.Add(items3);
        lstDouble.Add(items4);
        lstDouble.Add(items5);

        var sum = lstDouble.SelectMany(x => x).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this using AsQueryable() of linq!**

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double totalSum = 0;
        List<int> list = new List<int> { 99, 34, 77, 75, 87,77, 35, 88};
        var listOfLists = list.Where(a => a == 77).ToList();
        int res = listOfLists.AsQueryable().Sum();
       
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```